# How do I make floated elements stack vertically instead of horizontally in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a web page with a two columns with one side having the main content and the other having extra stuff. But because I am using the float property to align the extra column to the left, it stacks horizontally but I want it to stack vertically.

My current code:

```
 .topicheader {
    padding: 2% 2%;
    float: left display: block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(40, 40, 40), rgb(50, 50, 50));
    font-size: 125%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px black;
  }

 .column.side {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
  }
```

```
  <div>
    <div class="def column side " ;>
      <strong class="topicheader">About</strong>
      <p style="color:white;">
       
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in euismod est. Curabitur euismod ultrices pellentesque. Morbi condimentum venenatis nibh sed feugiat.
      </p>
    </div>

     <div class="def column side " ;>
      <strong class="topicheader">About</strong>
      <p style="color:white;">
       
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in euismod est. Curabitur euismod ultrices pellentesque. Morbi condimentum venenatis nibh sed feugiat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried using the vertical-align property but it does nothing.
[What I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGC4E.png)

Comment: For a structure better use `grid` or `flex`. Read more on https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ at `display: flex` , `flex-direction: column` , and `flex-wrap: wrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `column` you stack the columns vertically. By using `row` the columns are side-by-side.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* stack vertically */
}
.column {
    height: 50vh; /* half of view height */
}

/* for example some colors */
.column:first-child {
    background-color: orange;
    color: blue;
}
.column:last-child {
    background-color: blue;
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="def column side">
        <strong class="topicheader">About</strong>
        <p style="color:white;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in euismod est. Curabitur euismod ultrices pellentesque. Morbi condimentum venenatis nibh sed feugiat.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="def column side">
        <strong class="topicheader">About</strong>
        <p style="color:white;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in euismod est. Curabitur euismod ultrices pellentesque. Morbi condimentum venenatis nibh sed feugiat.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear: both;` property.

```css
.column.side{
    clear:both;
}
```